# How to add a package declaration to java generated by SWIG

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate a bunch of Java files -- I want the files to be part of a certain package ... right now after I generate them I have to go in and manually add the import declaration ... is there a way to template this into swig?

Answer (score 10):

Just need to specify the package as follows

```
mkdir -p com/example/package
swig -java -package com.example.package -outdir com/example/package example.i
```